# how to doPost of multiple values of inputs with same name

Tags: google-apps-script

i have the following code which works well

```
function doGet(e) {
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }

function doPost(e){ 
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

  try {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var row = [ new Date() ];

  for(var i=1; i< headers.length; i++){
    if(headers[i].length>0) {
      row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);   
  }
}
```

now i need to add in the html form new input fields having the same name, the new values i want to post them in the sheet in a new row.

maybe some `for` loop inside doPost will solve it? thanks for any help

html form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPT_ID/exec">

 <input name="type" value="test1"/>
 <input name="John" value="90"/>
 <input name="Lisa" value=""/>
 <input name="Sam" value="80"/>

 <input name="type" value="test2"/>
 <input name="John" value="40"/>
 <input name="Lisa" value="60"/>
 <input name="Sam" value="100"/>

 <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

my Sheet as follow:

```
timestamp  |  type   |  John    |   Lisa     |    Sam
6/01/2020  |  test1  |   90     |     -      |    80
6/01/2020  |  test2  |   40     |     60     |    100
```

i need to post all the data (in 2 rows) in one submit form (click).

Comment: Can you explain about the current issue of your script? And in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the script of `the html form`? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: This code is working correctly : ```<input name="name01" value= "1st value" />``` now i need to add new input under the same name in order to put them in the sheet in the same column, so i need to add ```<input name="name01" value= "2nd value" />```  my issue is the script which is adding only one row so it receives only the first value, the 2nd value is not received in the sheet.

Comment: Did you review documentation for the event object that is received by doPost? It specifies exactly how you can access **parameter*s*** that may appear multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the script of `the html form`? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: For your initial question, I could confirm that the script works. But in your environment, the script didn't work because the updated question was different from the initial one. Also, for your updated question, I could confirm that the script works. But in your replying, the script didn't work. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation. Under this situation, I cannot resolve your issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I could correctly understand about your situation, I would like to answer to it.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @Tanaike the solution of kessy was useful for me, thanks for your time, by the way your English skill is very good bro, better than me! i apologize because i couldn't make my situation clear for you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. The reason that my sample script cannot be used for your situation is due to my poor skill. I thought that I have to apologize for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code I came up with a solution working as you want it. This solution can work either with 2 or more rows of input data.

What I have done here is iterate through every header and set the data column by column, not row by row like you did and all that it does is going through each header, in the header gets each value and sets it in the correct column.

This is the script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function doPost(e){  
  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET ID");
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var columns = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
    var nextColumn = 2;
    var row = [ new Date() ];
    var columnTi;
    var newNextRow = 0;
    for(var i=1; i< headers.length; i++){
      var columnRange = sheet.getRange(nextRow, nextColumn)
      for(var j=0; j< e.parameters[headers[i]].length; j++){
        newNextRow = nextRow + j;
        columnRange = sheet.getRange(newNextRow, nextColumn)
        sheet.getRange(newNextRow, 1).setValue(new Date())
        sheet.getRange(columnRange.getA1Notation()).setValue(e.parameters[headers[i]][j])
      }

      nextColumn++;

    }

  }
  catch(e){Logger.log(e)}
}
```

Comment: What a damn solution! it works like the magic as i want exactly! Million thanks pal.